# How do I enable Chrome DevTools Experiments?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've just installed Google Canary on my Mac.  I want to have a play with the Experiments in the google developer tools.  But I can't for the life of me find where/how to enable them.

I specifically want to look at using/editing SASS in the browser.

Thanks
dave

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found it

In chrome go to chrome://flags and enable it there.

1. Go to `chrome://flags`.
2. Find **Developer Tools Experiments**.
3. Enable it.
4. Click **Relaunch Now** to relaunch Chrome.

In the DevTools settings, there's now a new **Experiments** tab.

Cheers

Comment: I just installed Google Chrome Version 89.0.4387.3 (Official Build) canary (64-bit). When I search in chrome://flags, I could not find "Developer Tools Experiments". What version of chrome canary is needed to find this flag?

Comment: It is no longer necessary to enable this via chrome:flags for the Protocol Monitor. You can skip this step