# Can I save CSS style changes from the Google DevTools Element > Styles tab, or must I go to the Sources tab?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, autosave

Today I learned about Google Chrome's ability to set up workspaces and map them to your local resources. This works perfectly in the `Sources` tab, but I'd like to be able to edit the css in the `Elements` > `Styles` tab so that I can see the changes as I make them. Otherwise I might as well just copy them into my editor since I have to reload the page to see the changes.

Is it possible to save changes from the `Elements` tab? I'd like the functionality similar to [Chrome DevTools Autosave](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave) if it is built into Chrome already.

This is the same question as [Chrome Workspaces - Saves changes in Sources tab but not Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657625/chrome-workspaces-saves-changes-in-sources-tab-but-not-elements), but none of the solutions work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The new, experimental Workspaces 2.0 handles it the way you're looking for.

1. Download [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html).
2. [Enable DevTools Experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15680012/1669860).
3. Open DevTools.
4. Open [Command Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41192408/1669860).
5. Type `Settings` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Go to **Experiments** tab.
7. Enable **Persistence 2.0**.
8. Restart Chrome.

[image: such persist, much convenient]

Comment: I have canary but I don't see an Experiments tab or anything about Persistence. Only Preferences, Workspace, Blackboxing, Devices, Throttling, and shortcuts.

Comment: I found Persistence 2.0 by first enabling "Developer Tools Experiments" at `chrome://flags/`, but it's still not saving for me even after a restart.

Comment: Oh, right. Forgot you had to enable experiments. So you enabled experiments and Persistence 2.0, and then restarted Chrome, and it's still not working?

Comment: Yes. I deleted the Workspace and started over, but now I do not have the mapping option. In the workspaces tab it says: `Mappings are inferred automatically via the 'Persistence 2.0' experiment.` however, the styles are not saving from the Elements > Styles tab

Comment: it looks that 'Persistence 2.0'  is now used by default. At east, I couldn't see it available in the "Experiments".

The problem I have: server load a static JS file with "cache busting" in the query string. And I need Chrome to substitute that file with my local version, ignoring any query string parameters… Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add folder to workspace
2. Map to File System Resource…
3. Change the styles in Elements Tab, after that enter **Tab** or **enter**

After these steps, all your change are in your local mapped files.

Comment: isn't there a way to just export the changes directly to the console though? that's really a dangerous/destructive process.

Comment: @robertotomás u can find the file u modified in Elements Style tab, then click , it would be displayed in Source panel, right click the file, use the Save as ... option to export the file. Moreover, u can find the modification history in the console drawer, u can revert your change to get back to earlier state.