# How do I open the Chrome DevTools command menu?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How do people access the command menu in the screenshot below?

[image: chrome devtools command menu]

Comment: The shortcuts are described in the documentation, it takes just a couple of minutes to skim through it and remember a few that you deem useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Open DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#open).
2. While the DevTools window is in focus, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac)
   or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows, Linux).

Comment: F12 in windows :)

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles on this: You have to press `Ctrl+Shift+P` while the DevTools (F12) are open.

Comment: Is there really no other way to do this?? I have that shortcut bound globally to do something else.

Answer (score 8):

If you're unable to use keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), you can also click the three stacked dots in the upper right-hand corner of the Developer Tools and choose "Run command." This will launch the Command Menu.

[image: Screenshot of Developer Tools menu]