# Long frame debugging in chrome devtools timeline

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, google-chrome-devtools

I am having trouble debugging my javascript performance in chrome devtools. I am doing some heavy animations, and I encountered something I don't understand in my timeline (while running some animations).

I marked click events with red circles. The blue squares with green 'animation' written on them are animations (what a surprise). And the red square is where I have my problem.

[image]

It takes between 300-400 ms, and happens after the animation ends. The call stack is nearly empty, and I am no devtools expert. Is there something obvious going on, that I don't see?

Also, if I wait a little longer the animations runs smoother, and those red long frames are gone.

In the project I use Backbone, underscore, jQuery and TweenMax for animations.

Comment: You mean red circles not green circles?

Comment: Are you seeing any jank during these periods? In other words, does the UX deteriorate during these periods? Or are you just confused as to why the FPS appears to drop? Because I'm not seeing much CPU activity during the problem periods. The fact that you don't see the red long frames all the time ("if I wait a little longer... those red long frames are gone") might just mean it's a quirk in the DevTools UI.

Comment: P.S. based on the Memory charts, it looks like your animations might have a leak. Might want to keep an eye on that.

Comment: Another tool that you can use to check FPS is the FPS Meter. Open the [Command Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41192409/1669860), type `Rendering` to open the Rendering Settings drawer, enable **FPS Meter**. If the FPS Meter says that your FPS is OK during the "problem periods", then it's just a quirk in Timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from how your Timeline panel looks I'm guessing you are using older version of Chrome. Please update to v57. There was a bug in previous versions where expected delay between animations was marked red (long frame). See [this report](https://crbug.com/640976).

#### Chrome 52:

[image]

#### Chrome 57:

[image]